# Repeating elements in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with elements:

```
a = ['Monica', 'Mark', 'Nick', 'Margaret']
```

and I'd like to obtain the following list of names:

```
['Monica', 'Monica', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Margaret', 'Margaret']
```

The simplest solution I came up with is:

```
lnames = []

for i, j in zip(a,a):
        lnames.append(i)
        lnames.append(j)
```

I've also tried to use a comprehension list:

```
lnames2 = [list(x) for x in zip(a,a)]
```

but in this case I'm getting:

```
[['Monica', 'Monica'], ['Mark', 'Mark'], ['Nick', 'Nick'], ['Margaret', 'Margaret']]
```

and don't know how to get the desire list from that point.

I'd like to ask you what are your solutions for this task.

Comment: "The simplest solution [you] came up with" works... what is the problem?

Comment: I'd use `[x for x in a for _ in range(2)]`, grab each element and repeat it twice...

Comment: What does this have to do with Pandas?

Comment: I have voted to close this as unclear what you are asking because you have a code that does exactly what you want.  I don't get what more you are expecting.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen OP want list, getting list of list.

Comment: `new_list = [item for item in prev_list for i in range("# of times to repeat")]`?

Comment: @Merlin the comprehension doesn't do what they want but the loop with `.append`s does do exactly what they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def repeat(collection, count):
    for x in collection:
        for i in range(count):
            yield x

a = ['Monica', 'Mark', 'Nick', 'Margaret']

print [x for x in repeat(a, 2)]
```

prints

```
['Monica', 'Monica', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Margaret', 'Margaret']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
import itertools

a = ['Monica', 'Mark', 'Nick', 'Margaret']

num_repeats = 2
lnames2 = list(itertools.chain(*[[x] * num_repeats for x in a]))
print(lnames2)
```

Comment: minus one-- sledgehammer to crack a walnut.

Comment: @Merlin The simplest solution for the particular case n=2 was already presented by OP's in his initial question. This is just a generic solution using python standard library, OP's main requirements was just `what are your solutions for this task`, so I'm not sure why you'd say this is minus one

Comment: .@BPL Would you actually use this?

Comment: @Merlin It depends of the use-case, let's say I'm coding a real time application where i got a certain ammount of few ms to generate many thousands of repeated elements per frame, the performance probably wouldn't be good enough so I wouldn't. On the other hand, if my application is not high performance and this oneliner did the job, why not? "Beautiful is better than ugly". Do you think having a custom function like the accepted answer is a best choice then?

Comment: .@BPL, I would chose the answer from the comments.